# Why are the borders on my BoxViews round?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I´m trying to create a s**eparator between StackLayouts** in a XAML page in Xamarin.Forms and I can do that easily with BoxView.

But when I try to add a border to the BoxView (by adding a Frame) I can´t get it to **not curve** at the ends.

[image]

I have tried all kinds of ways to make this work without luck. I even tried to stretch the BoxView **out of the screen** (take a look at the latter image) to have the curve off the screen (**that would just do fine at this moment even**)

Here is **just few** of of the things I tried out without any luck.

```
<!--Test 1. -->
      <Frame OutlineColor="{DynamicResource CardOutlineColor}" HasShadow="False" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <BoxView x:Name="boxViewSeparator" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="10000" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource WindowsBackgroundColor}" />
      </Frame>
      
 <!--Test 2. -->
      <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Frame OutlineColor="{DynamicResource CardOutlineColor}" HasShadow="False" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

          <BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0"
                      Color="#f2f3f3"
                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource WindowsBackgroundColor}" />
        </Frame>
      </AbsoluteLayout>

 <!--Test3. -->
      <Frame OutlineColor="{DynamicResource CardOutlineColor}" HasShadow="False" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ContentView HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource WindowsBackgroundColor}" />
      </Frame>

 <!--Test 4. -->
      <Frame OutlineColor="{DynamicResource CardOutlineColor}" HasShadow="False" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ContentView HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource WindowsBackgroundColor}" MinimumWidthRequest="500"/>
      </Frame>
```

I came the closest with this this code

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Frame OutlineColor="{DynamicResource CardOutlineColor}" HasShadow="False"
               Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.5, 1.5, 1.2, 1.0">
          <BoxView  HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource WindowsBackgroundColor}" />
        </Frame>
      </AbsoluteLayout>
```

**But** the result is that I only get the other part of the ViewBox out of the window

Does anybody have any other idea?

[image]

Comment: _Why are the borders on my BoxViews round?_ - because you wrapped it in `Frame`.

Comment: But why does the frame not wrap around the BoxView's frame? Why does it curve when the BoxView doesn't?  Do you know how to strech the BoxView out of the screen at both ends?

Comment: Or stretch the frame out of the screen?

Comment: `Frame` has default rounded border(`BoxView` doesn't) and you are not able to manage it from box, you could create custom renderer and manage corner radius in platform specific way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how to do this and like everything you know, it´s easy :-)

Just use **3 BoxViews in a StackLayout** without padding/spacing.

```
    <StackLayout Orientation ="Vertical" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
      <BoxView BackgroundColor="#d6dbdb" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
      <BoxView HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="#f2f3f3"/>
      <BoxView BackgroundColor="#d6dbdb" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

And the result is the following.
[image]

p.s
I would like to see how you would off set the frame off the screen...

Answer (score 0):

I've found more elegant solution(IMHO):

Create custom box view:

```
public class Border : BoxView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor),
                                typeof(Color),
                                typeof(Border),
                                Color.Transparent);

    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderWidthProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderWidth),
                                typeof(double),
                                typeof(Border),
                                0d);

    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public double BorderWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BorderWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderWidthProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Implement renderers:

**ANDROID**

```
public class BorderRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<BoxView>
{
    public BorderRenderer()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        SetWillNotDraw(false);

        Invalidate();
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        var border = Element as Border;

        base.Draw(canvas);

        var paint = new Paint();
        paint.StrokeWidth = (float)border.BorderWidth;
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.SetARGB(ConvertTo255ScaleColor(border.BorderColor.A), ConvertTo255ScaleColor(border.BorderColor.R), ConvertTo255ScaleColor(border.BorderColor.G), ConvertTo255ScaleColor(border.BorderColor.B));

        SetLayerType(Android.Views.LayerType.Software, paint);

        var number = (float)border.BorderWidth / 2;
        var rectF = new RectF(
                    number, // left
                    number, // top
                    canvas.Width - number, // right
                    canvas.Height - number // bottom
            );


        canvas.DrawRoundRect(rectF, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    private int ConvertTo255ScaleColor(double color)
    {
        return (int)Math.Ceiling(color * 255);
    }
}
```

**iOS**

```
public class BorderRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<BoxView>
{
    public BorderRenderer()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element == null)
            return;

        Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        Layer.CornerRadius = 0f;
    }

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        var border = (Border)Element;
        using (var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            context.SetFillColor(border.Color.ToCGColor());
            context.SetStrokeColor(border.BorderColor.ToCGColor());
            context.SetLineWidth((float)border.BorderWidth);

            var rCorner = Bounds.Inset((int)border.BorderWidth / 2, (int)border.BorderWidth / 2);

            var radius = (nfloat)border.CornerRadius;
            radius = (nfloat)Math.Max(0, Math.Min(radius, Math.Max(rCorner.Height / 2, rCorner.Width / 2)));

            var path = CGPath.FromRoundedRect(rCorner, radius, radius);
            context.AddPath(path);
            context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add attribute above `namespace` on each renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Border), typeof(BorderRenderer))]
```